# A point below the graph of a convex function lies on a line below the graph

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function. If $y<\varphi(x)$ why does there exist a line through $(x,y)$ which lies strictly below the graph of $\varphi$?  I ask because this is a step in the proof of Jensen's inequality for conditional expectation.

Answer (score 0):

One of the properties of convex functions is:

> If $\varphi:(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ is convex, and $t_0 \in (a,b)$, there exists $\beta\in \mathbb{R}$ such that
>   \begin{equation}
> \varphi(x) - \varphi(t_0) \geq \beta(x-t_0)
> \end{equation}
>   for all $t\in(a,b)$ where $(-\infty \leq a < b \leq \infty)$.

and by rearrangement there is a line passing through $(t_0, \varphi(x))$ for all $t_0\in (a,b)$.
Let $\delta = \varphi(t_0) - y > 0$, and shift this line by $\delta$ to get the desired line.

---

$\varphi$ is convex if
\begin{equation}
\frac{\varphi(t)-\varphi(s)}{t-s} \leq \frac{\varphi(t')-\varphi(s')}{t'-s'}
\end{equation}
for all $s,t,s',t'\in (a,b)$ such that $s\leq s' \leq t'$ and $s< t \leq t'$.

Fix $s < t_0 < s'$.
 If $s' < t$, 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\varphi(s')-\varphi(s)}{s'-s} \leq \frac{\varphi(t)-\varphi(t_0)}{t-t_0}
\end{equation}
If $t<s$,
\begin{equation}
\frac{\varphi(t_0)-\varphi(t)}{t_0-t} \leq \frac{\varphi(s')-\varphi(s)}{s'-s}
\end{equation}
Choose $\beta = (\varphi(s')-\varphi(s))/(s'-s)$. As pointed out, convex functions are differentiable almost everywhere. In that case, $\beta = \varphi'(t_0)$.

Comment: When you say "equivalent definition of convex" do you mean "property of convex function"? Surely not every function with secants of bounded slope is convex, right?

Comment: also when you say "there is a line passing through $(t_0, \varphi(x))$ for all $t_0\in (a,b)$"  do you mean the horizontal line $y= \varphi(x)$?

Comment: Exactly,  my bad. Edited. Line $\ell$ is given as $\ell(x) = \beta(x-t_0) + \varphi(t_0)$, which is always smaller than $\varphi(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the line that passes through $(x -h, \varphi(x-h))$ and $(x +h, \varphi(x+h))$

Choose $x$ the midpoint of $x -h$ and $x+h$

Clearly the point $(x, \frac{\varphi(x+h) + \varphi(x-h)}{2})$ is on the line passing through $(x -h, \varphi(x-h))$ and $(x +h, \varphi(x+h))$.

Therefore equation of this line is:

$$y_1(x_1) = \frac{\varphi(x+h) - \varphi(x-h)}{2h}(x_1 - x) + \frac{\varphi(x+h) + \varphi(x-h)}{2}$$

By point slope from high school algebra.

Using the definition of convexity:
$$\frac{\varphi(x+h) + \varphi(x-h)}{2} > \varphi(x)$$

$$\implies y_1(x_1) > \frac{\varphi(x+h) - \varphi(x-h)}{2h}(x_1 - x) + \phi(x)$$

If we take the limit as $h\to 0$ ($h$ is arbitrary anyway), the above relation says that:

$$y_1(x_1) > \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\varphi(x+h) - \varphi(x-h)}{2h}(x_1 - x) + \phi(x) = \varphi'(x)(x_1 -x) + \varphi(x)$$

What's remarkable about this is that the above is exactly equation of the line tangent to $\varphi$ at $x$. This means that the tangent line to $\varphi(x)$ at $x$ is below $\varphi(x^1)$ for all $x^1 \not = x$ since we can always choose $h$ such that $x + h = x^1$ and $\varphi(x^1)$ lies on a line that is above the tangent line to $\varphi(x)$ at $x^1$.

Suppose now that we run a line through $(x, y)$ with slope $\varphi'(x)$, that line has equation:

$$y_2(x_2) = \varphi'(x)(x_2 - x) + y$$

Because $y < \varphi(x)$ and from the work we did above,

$$\varphi(x_2) > y_1(x_2) > y_2(x_2)$$

for all $x_2$.

$$$$

Thus, we've constructed a line $y_2(x_2)$ that passes through $y$ such that $y_2(x_2) < \varphi(x_2)$ for all $x_2$.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you assume that $\varphi$ is differentiable at $x$?

Comment: Yes. I did in order to take a finite difference approach / provide some intuition as to why it works. If you don't want to, then use the expression for the difference quotient and make $h$ small enough s.t. the drop between $\varphi(x)$ and $y$ "cancels out" the small set of points that $y_1$ is above when it passes through $\varphi(x)$. Also, doesn't the proof of jensen's inequality taylor expand the function of the expectation?

Comment: I was reading the proof given here (lemma 6.10). http://www.math.ucla.edu/~biskup/275b.1.14w/PDFs/conditional-expectation.pdf  What they need there is a bit weaker than what I asked for, so your proof probably works for my purposes.

Comment: anyway, thanks again. I'll have to pore over this later today.